# Python install pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am running Os X 10.11.3 and I am having trouble installing pandas. I have two Anaconda environments installed (3.5 and 2.7), and I code using CodeRunner. I have searched through all the forums and tried the suggested advice, but nothing seems to work.

When I type

```
conda list
```

in terminal, it shows that pandas is installed, but when I try to import into CodeRunner, it returns with ImportError: No module named pandas. Note that importing numpy succeeds without problem.

I also have

```
#!/Users/username/anaconda/bin/python
```

at the top of .py files in CodeRunner. This is the directory that is outputted in terminal when I type *which python*. By default, CodeRunner had

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

I am not 100% sure what difference this makes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `/Users/brendan/anaconda/bin` is the path to your Python executable, try this in your Bash prompt and see what happens:

```
/Users/brendan/anaconda/bin/python -m pip install pandas
```

Comment: When I type that in terminal I get the following:

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pandas in ./anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil>=2 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz>=2011k in ./anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.7.0 in ./anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pandas)

Comment: This means that Pandas is installed for your Anaconda Python(s). However, you mentioned that you have more than one Python installed, in which case, you need to find out which Python environment is it that you're trying to use Pandas at, and receive an error. You can do that by running this command inside the environment (i.e. CodeRunner): `from sys import executable` and then `print(executable)` in Python3 or `print executable` in Python2. Take note of the output (copy it?) and the replace the path above with that output like so `the_output_path -m pip install pandas`. See what happens.

Comment: The executable was /usr/bin/python and I copied that into terminal with -m pip install pandas and got the following: /usr/bin/python: No module named pip . I have two python environments using anaconda, and I believe that there is a default one on Apple computers. Is there a way to change my executable so that it just points to one of the anaconda distributions, or am I looking at the problem incorrectly?

Comment: Run `easy_install pip` to install `pip`. And no, don't play with default interpreters, especially since you're not very familiar with the details. You'll end up crashing half of the operations that depend on Python in your OS.

Comment: But then what's the point in having Anaconda distributions? They have all the packages I want, but I can't use them in CodeRunner? I installed pip, but I am still getting the same error message: /usr/bin/python: No module named pip

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't do it like this: `the_path_you_found -m easy_install pip` , right? And nothing. There is no point to it. I never use it, even if it's installed somewhere! I'd rather do thing myself and make sure they're done they way I expect them to. I assume CodeRunner has an option to change interpreters, but I don't know it since I don't use CodeRunner. I use PyCharm for large projects and vim/emacs for smaller ones!

Comment: Thanks for your help! It appears that Anaconda isn't compatible with CodeRunner. I'm going to try to use Spyder.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I seriously suggest that you give PyCharm a go. It gives you the ability to manage packages, change interpreter, and create Virtual Environments. It's free as long as you're not selling the what you're producing in it! All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I know this is very late, but if anyone finds this, maybe this will help...
Coderunner is running the built in python (/usr/bin/python), not one of the anaconda versions with pandas. In Coderunner "Run settings", you will see that it runs "python $filename", which take precedence over what you have on the first line of the file. (On my mac (10.13), python has NumPy but not pandas, )

Maybe it is as easy as changing Coderunner "Run setting" python to /Users/username/anaconda/bin/python.