# How to plug python in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I openned my a notebook in jupyter, but coldn't run it. In corner was text `kernel error`. Sorting out in problem i understood, that python isn't plugged in jupiter notebok

Want to mention, that i installed jupiter with pip, i don't use anaconda. Today i downloaded python from microsoft store and after it donloaded jupiter using common command in python.

I openned Jupyter from command line (my os is windows 10 x64) using command

```
python -m notebook
```

Then from my desktop i openned notebook downloaded from web; it openned in correct view. But no kernels work.

Also i found error message in cmd, where i started notebook. There was wrote `ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.`.

But further more. I tried to press `ctrl + c` in cmd to enterrupt kernels, but there was wrote, `shutted down 0 kernels`. That mean, python just wasn't plugged in jupiter notebook. I suppose, it's the source of the problem.

As solution i decided to install anaconda. But maybe someone knows, how to fix this problem.

Comment: I suspect that are you using enviornment or not. Please check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46353215/import-error-dll-load-failed-in-jupyter-notebook-but-working-in-py-file]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should upgrade your prompt toolkit

Try this:

`pip install --upgrade prompt-toolkit`