# Conda Jupyer Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

After creating an environment in anaconda and installing tensorflow, I could not open Jupyter notebook, do I have to switch to base environment to open the notebook or I have done something wrong

```
D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cffi\__pycache__\_cffi_ext.c(213): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/un.h': No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Does jupyter work in the base environment?

Comment: have u tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46353215/import-error-dll-load-failed-in-jupyter-notebook-but-working-in-py-file ??

Comment: So I installed jupyter notebook in that environment and it worked. It is not an ideal solution but it works.

Comment: @James yes jupyter works in the base environment

Comment: @spYder nope it didn't work for me