# Jupyter notebook doesn't launch (Windows 10)

Tags: python-3.x, windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I just installed Anaconda 3 following the instructions of the Windows 10 installer. Now I want to launch a jupyter notebook from the command line but I get the error :

```
_cffi_ext.c
Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cffi\__pycache__\_cffi_ext.c(213): fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier include : 'sys/un.h' : No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lafon\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\lafon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "C:\Users\lafon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\lafon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\lafon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\lafon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\lafon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\lafon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

After the installation I did 2 things :

- run `conda init` in the terminal
- add path to Anaconda3 and to Anaconda3\Scripts to my Path environment variable.

Thank you for your help,

Marc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import error: DLL load failed in Jupyter notebook but working in .py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46353215/import-error-dll-load-failed-in-jupyter-notebook-but-working-in-py-file)

Comment: Yes it does ! 
Since I want to be able to launch a jupyter notebook without activate base environement I have added the following to mentionned paths to my Path environnement variable.