# DLL load failed: Specified module not found in jupyter notebook import

Tags: dll, jupyter-notebook

Apologies for any mistakes, I'm new to this. I installed a program in jupyter notebook it contains a bunch of .ipynb files and a folder which contains a bunch of .dll files and then persis_homo_optimal.py. Then in one of the .ipynb files it has code

```
from persis_homo_optimal import *
```

The error I get:

```
DLL load failed while importing _persis_homo_optimal: The specified module could not be found.
```

Now what I tried (from another stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46353215/import-error-dll-load-failed-in-jupyter-notebook-but-working-in-py-file)) is running `activate base` in the anaconda terminal and then restarting jupyter notebook, but it still does not work. What do I do?

Comment: [\[SO\]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883130/4788546).

Comment: Tip to make your post better: It looks like you are attempting to run things from here (or somehow related to that)? So include that information.  Tell us the source of things. Because I suspect it is [this](https://github.com/TopoXLab/TopoGAN-ECCV2020)?  Which looks like it would be challenging even for someone familiar with this stuff. Did you see the note that begins - "Update 1/28/2023:"? [This diff of the commit](https://github.com/TopoXLab/TopoGAN-ECCV2020/commit/aae68a9f6df2e1f7fcb956178025b755bee9349b) highlights the change. They seem to be open to contact.