# error when connecting pytrends in Jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, importerror, traceback

I am using :

- Python 3.6.6
- Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6

and the following website to help me install pytrends https://pypi.org/project/pytrends/

I am following the instructions to download pytrends and installed the requirements to run pytrends "*requests*, *lxml*, & *pandas*". Here are the instructions

1. Install *pytrends* `pip install pytrends`
2. Connect *pytrends* to google

`from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrends = TrendReq(hl=’en-US’, tz=360)`

but I get the following error

```
File "<ipython-input-1-e31d93dc256d>", line 2
pytrends = TrendReq(hl=’en-US’, tz=360)
                         ^ SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

so I researched for information to help me and found a code that worked better for me from https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/blob/master/README.md

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReqpytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360)
```

but I received the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-9d1eaf7e6778a>in <module>() ----> 
  1 from pytrends.request import TrendReq
  2 
  3 pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytrends'
```

I ran the above mentioned code in Jupiter labs. My guess is that I have to import pytrends in Jupiter lab. I installed pytrends but through terminal not Jupyter labs. I will try `!pip3 install pytrends` in Jupiter lab. I got this idea by reading an issue someone has from

https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/issues/248

In addition to link above, I found two other relevant questions on stack overflow that might help me solve this issue :

[Jupyter Notebook: no module named pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043407/jupyter-notebook-no-module-named-pandas)

[numpy & pandas 'ModuleNotFoundEror' in Jupyter notebook (Python 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872617/numpy-pandas-modulenotfounderor-in-jupyter-notebook-python-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you install pyTrends from the command line, inside of Jupyter Lab you want to instantiate a new note book and run the following code and you will be able to print Google Trends data for the period found in the `_timeframe` variable I have declared.

Change the search term in `kw_list` to the term that you are looking for search trend data on as follows:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a Google Trend Object

totalTrend = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360)

# Declare a var to store the search term
#### build the playload
kw_list = ["bitcoin"]  
_cat = 0
_geo = ''
_gprop = ''

# Build payload request to get data from Google trends
_timeframe = '2009-01-03 2018-05-26'

totalTrend.build_payload(kw_list, cat=_cat, timeframe=_timeframe, geo=_geo, gprop=_gprop)

# Get interest over time
# Capture Monthly Data for use in Normalization against Weekly
totalTrend = totalTrend.interest_over_time()

# Plot the Interest
totalTrend.plot(title='Google Trends Monthly Data Points', figsize=(20,10))
```